# Finding related images using its tags

Tags: sql, subquery

Here is a table that connects multiple `tags` to an `image`

```
| image_id | tag_id   |
|:---------|---------:|

| 1        | 43       |
| 1        | 34       |
| 1        | 12       |
| 1        | 4        |
| 1        | 23       |
| 1        | 5        |

| 2        | 4        |
| 2        | 23       |
| 2        | 53       |
| 2        | 43       |
| 2        | 24       |
| 2        | 44       |

| 3        | 5        |
| 3        | 12       |
| 3        | 4        |
| 3        | 53       |
| 3        | 44       |

| 4        | 100      |
| 4        | 120      |
| 4        | 433      |
| 4        | 532      |
| 4        | 441      |
```

I want to write a SQL Query that will return related image's that is ordered by the most related to another by their tags (the more tags they share the higher it will be).

---

Image id `1` and image id `2` share 4 tag id's `43`, `4`, `23`, `4`

Image id `1` and image id `3` share 3 tag ids `12`, `4`, `5`

Image id `1` and image id `4` share 0 tag ids

*So image `2` and `3` would be returned with `2` being above `3` because it has more tags in common and `4` would be excluded because it doesn't share any tags.*

---

This is what I have got so far, and it seems to work but without an order of most related to least.

```
    SELECT *
    FROM image_tag i
    JOIN tag t
    ON t.tag_id = i.tag_id
    WHERE i.tag_id IN (
        SELECT tag_id 
        FROM image_tag
        WHERE image_id = 1)
    AND image_id != 1
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the inputs and outputs. Can you possibly provide another example dataset, perhaps with 5 or 6 related tags per image?

Comment: @PP. I have added a larger dataset and hopefully a clearer explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Are u expecting your result something like in the link below:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/57609/3

If yes. you can use that sql or please paste your output version also.